# Problem Plotting `Module` Output

Tags: plotting, scoping

I have code that automatically outputs a parametric function that's found by using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

[image]

I'm using a `Module` to automatically solve the equation. I'm posting these as images because there's just too much code to post, but I can post the code if there's no way of solving this by inspection.

When I solve for this parametric function and output it manually I get this instead (without `Module`):

[image]

They seem to be exactly the same, except the first one is in deconstructed form, showing all the "insides". The problem is that I can't seem to `Plot` the first function, but I can `Plot` the second one. This might have something to do with the `Module` creating local variables that *Mathematica* can't later use when plotting but I'm not sure.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

*Edit:*
When I was trying to recreate the problem I found the solution. Here is what I meant -- we use a `ParametricNDSolveValue` in the setup to solve this differential equation and plot it:

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[t] == Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2], z[0] == 0}, z, {t, 0, x}, {x}]; 
g = s[x];
```

You plot $g(x)$ and the curve appears. Then, I put this inside a `Module` and called the `Module` and wrapped an `ExpandAll` around it to see all the terms:

```
test = Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (x - t)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -t^2];

y[test_] := Module[{}, s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[t] == test, z[0] == 0}, z, {t, 0, x}, {x}];
g = s[x]]
```

This is the calling function here:

```
ans[x_] = ExpandAll[y[test][x]]
```

It produces the output seen in the first image above, with all the crazy detail. If you try to plot it, no curve shows up. I originally thought this was because of `Module`, but actually it's because of `ExpandAll`. If you remove `ExpandAll`, you can plot $ans(x)$. Somehow one thing interferes with another.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them unreadable. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: It's much worse than "no solution by inspection": what you have posted is extremely fragmentary information with pieces missing, which in fact is total nonsense in its current form. Your description is also not clear: `Module` is a scoping construct, so one can only wonder how it is used to solve anything. Please construct and post a minimal (not) working example, otherwise the chances of anyone being able to help you are extremely slim. Your other questions are good, so I expect you know the drill by now.

Comment: I updated the post and I think I found the solution as well. Thanks for keeping me in check @OleksandrR.